# How to design progress bar with text of its value?

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can I create something like this progress bar?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply nest a div in another div and set the width of the nested div to the progress percentage. You can align the text with `text-align:center`.

```css
.progress-bar{
  background-color:#EAECEF;
}
.progress-bar .bar{
  background-color:#314EFF;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar" style="width:49%">
    49%
  </div>
</div>
```